# SSL-specific hostname in Heroku with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, https, hostname

I currently have a setup where I force SSL or http where I need it with this before_filter in my application controller:

```
def force_ssl
  if params[:controller] == "sessions"
    if !request.ssl? && Rails.env.production?
      redirect_to :protocol => 'https://', :status => :moved_permanently
    end
  else
    if request.ssl? && Rails.env.production?
      redirect_to :protocol => 'http://', :status => :moved_permanently
    end
  end
end
```

What I'd like to do is to use `https://secure.example.com` when using SSL but keep using `http://example.com` when not using SSL. Is there a way I can switch between the hostnames depending on whether I'm using SSL?

Comment: Why bother forcing your users to authenticate via SSL when, as soon as the authentication is done, anybody can hack their sessions with e.g. firesheep, the free session-hacking firefox addon. If you try to use SSL in this way, you are not protecting your users. Instead, if some part of your site needs to be delivered over SSL, then from an actual security perspective it is likely that every part of your site needs to be delivered over SSL too (or, at least, every part following the authentication).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I'll show how to force SSL in current and earlier versions of Rails, then at the end I've posted how to use HTTP and HTTPS in Parallel with each other, which is what I think your looking for.

**Rails >= 3.1**
Simply use `config.force_ssl = true` in your environment configuration.

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.force_ssl = true
  end
end
```

You can also selectively enable https depending on the current Rails environment. For example, you might want to keep HTTPS turned off on development, and enable it on staging/production.

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.force_ssl = false
  end
end

# config/environments/production.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```

**Rails < 3.1**

Just in case you have any projects that are not Rails 3.1 and want the same feature. Enable HTTPS by adding the following line to your environment configuration.

`config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, "Rack::SSL"`

Note that I’m passing `Rack::SSL` as string to delegate the loading of the class at the end of the Rails application initialization. Also note the middleware must be inserted in a specific position in the stack, at least before `ActionDispatch::Static` and `ActionDispatch::Cookies`.

Don’t forget to define Rack::SSL dependency in your Gemfile.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rack-ssl', :require => 'rack/ssl'
```

**Enabling HTTPS and HTTP in parallel**

`Rack::SSL` has a very interesting and undocumented feature. You can pass an `:exclude` option to determine when to enable/disable the use of HTTPS.

The following code enables `Rack::SSL` and all its filters only in case the request comes from a HTTPS connection.

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::SSL, :exclude => proc { |env| env['HTTPS'] != 'on' }
```

Both the following URLs will continue to work, but the first one will trigger the `Rack::SSL` filters.

`https://secure.example.com`
`http://example.com`

Comment: I was using force_ssl before (I'm in Rails 3.1) but I didn't find a way for it to force http when I didn't want SSL, so I just rolled my own solution in my application controller instead. Is there a way to customize force_ssl?

Comment: You could write a custom Class Method in the ForceSSL module that could do just the opposite of ForceSSL, I could post an example if you want?